# binary log not getting generated on master for repliaction

Tags: mysql, database-replication

I am learning master/slave database replication. I want to log all the changes in all databases.

I have executed this query : insert into test_db.temp_tbl values(1); 
and I come across one odd thing that without doing 'use any_database' prior to query,it is not getting logged into binary logs.

can anyone shed light on it ?

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like the effect of replication rules.

There are rules both on the master and on the slave.

In your case is sounds like you have the config property [replicate-do-db](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replication-options-slave.html#option_mysqld_replicate-do-db) set to just have that db.

Comment: Andreas,the rules work in all cases except this and I am talking about binary log on master.What my understanding is that first log should come in binary log then and then only replication on slave is possible.

Comment: Depending on the rules on the master some statements are written to the binary log. How are your replication rules set up now?